# Insert values for column based on values of separate column (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

My table currently looks like this

```
 ID    NAMESITE SENSORTYPE ____(columns between) SENSORNUMBER(initialized to all null)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 SW02       random                                null--
 SW02       camera                                null--
 SW02       random                                null
 SW02       camera                                null
 NW02       RANDOm                                null
 NW02       camera                                null
 NW02       random                                null
 NW02       camera                                null
 NW02       camera                                null
```

Basically what I want to do is increment the sensor number if it comes in contact with a sensor type = 'camera' and if it comes in contact with 2 id's that are the same it should input the incremented value in the same row for sensor number 
HOWEVER all the ID-Sensor type which are NOT camera's can be left null

An example output should be like this

```
ID    NAMESITE SENSORTYPE ____(columns between) SENSORNUMBER(initialized entire Column NULL)
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SW02           random                              null--
SW02           camera                                 1
SW02           random                              null
SW02           camera                                 2
NW02           RANDOm                               null
NW02           camera                                 1
NW02           random                               null
NW02           camera                                 2
NW02           camera                                 3
```

I'm not sure how I want to accomplish this with C# or without and I'm not sure how to approach this, I assume I'll need to keep a running count any help ?

Please note I want to modify my EXISTING TABLE not create a new table(the first one is what my initial table looks like)

where SENSORTYPE = 'Camera' should be incremented if more then one of the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with an `update` and CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
      where sensortype = 'Camera'
     )
update toupdate
    set sensornumber = seqnum;
```

Note:  Your sensor numbers are increasing for each `id`.  But there is no (obvious) column for ordering the values.  If you have such a column, then the `order by` should use that column.  Otherwise, the values will be sequential but arbitrarily ordered.

Comment: In SQL query, correct?- what should I update as the table name?

Comment: It has to be the same ID and a Camera then it starts at 1 and further incrementing until it reaches a different ID with a CAMERA and restarts at 1 , all other values are null so wouldn't it be the Sensor type?

Comment: I'm using this and I'm getting values 92 , 93 for the first two sensor numbers then 94 , then 79, 80 for the next ones, it's all over the place-

Comment: How would I get it sequential STARTING from 1, not arbitrarily ordered.?

Answer (score 0):

To get a sequential implementation for the SENSOR number starting at 1(NOT ARBITRARLY)  I just created another row called rownum which kept track of the row#(1-endrow) and used the order by that so it wasn't using arbitrary numbers. - If anyone was wondering!